# I want to get the outside outline of a plane that is doubled up

Tags: python, objects

https://i.imgur.com/rUqIDSU.png
I have this flat shape see left side of image[image]

And I want to get just the outside outline of it. On the right side of the image you can see that I was able to get an outline using the following python.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
bpy.ops.mesh.dissolve_faces()
```

however as you can see there are still intersections within the mesh. I can't seem to figure out how to get only the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was dealing with this problem, I extruded the mesh then used intersect knife, to get the faces to interact, before merging doubles and re-collapsing it to a single plane.

Comment: I'm a little confused I've extruded and run the intersect knife. but I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Forgot to mention you will have to Run limited dissolve and possibly adjust the knife operator to make it work with selected to selected as opposed to selected to deselected.